# Finger dragging on ImageView

Tags: android

I'm trying to know the location of my finger when moving it on ImageView
but I only get Up and down on each touch.

```
    myIM = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    myIM.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
                    int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();
                    Log.d("DTAG","Move");
                    Log.d("DTAG","x: "+x);
                    Log.d("DTAG","y: "+y);
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    Log.d("DTAG","Down");
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    Log.d("DTAG","UP");
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Log:

```
D/DTAG: Down
D/DTAG: UP
D/DTAG: Down
D/DTAG: UP
```

Comment: Probably `break` for cases missing?

Comment: return `true` from `onTouch`

Comment: @pskink Thank you. Please post it as an answer